# CoreBluetooth `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices` returns disconnected peripherals

Tags: ios, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

I wonder about the semantics of `CBManager`'s `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices`. Everytime I'm using this I get `CBPeripheral` instances back with state `CBPeripheralStateDisconnected`.

It's not a problem to connect again, but isn't this method supposed to return *connected* peripherals?

Comment: "The list of connected peripherals can include those that are connected by other apps and that will need to be connected locally using the connectPeripheral:options: method before they can be used.". Do you have more than one CBCentralManager instance in your app?

Comment: No, just one (that said, let me check whether there's no leak). It even happens right after (successfully) connecting to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is intended behaviour. It is a bit counterintuitive I have to admit but the peripheral state is always related to your app. That means if you have connected/paired/bonded the peripheral using another app or via the bluetooth system settings, it will still show as disconnected within your app. If you have connected some peripherals within your app they will show as connected.

Comment: I can understand that the status in general is per-app due to the sandbox concept. I wonder though shouldn't I get at least a connected-state for devices that I have connected to _within_ my app or is it possible that the state is even isolated per CBCentralManager (i.e. for every new CBCentralManager, I always get 'disconnected' no matter what)?

Comment: Yes, that can happen as well. Peripherals from one `CBCentralManager` cannot be used in another `CBCentralManager`. I suggest using just one `CBCentralManager` otherwise you might run into trouble. There is a good read on the [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20810) on this topic.